# Is "gen" also a reading of this kanji? 間

Tags: kanji, readings

According to a page, this word is pronounced "ningen"

[image]

but according to another page, the readings for 間 are

[image]

Are they the same kanji? Is "gen" an unofficial reading or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called [Rendaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku). Regularly in compound words, though not always, the second part of a compound ends up voiced. So the reading of the kanji is in essence ケン, but with a dakuten (゛) or voice mark added to it. This gives us the reading ゲン as in the word 人間. It's not a very common reading though, personally I can only think of one other word using the ケン reading, and that is the word 世{せ}間{けん}.

Take the two words fire = 火{ひ} and flower = 花{はな}. Together they can form two new words, fireworks = 花{はな}火{び} and spark = 火{ひ}花{ばな}. The reading is the same in both except that when it appears last in a compound it gets voiced.

Why does the last part get voiced sometimes? I don't know, and I don't think anyone definitely knows. It could make it easier to say, or it makes the two parts more connected into a new words rather than the sum of its parts. Either way it's something the Japanese do and worth knowing about.

*Edit*:
Example, both 忠{ちゅう}告{こく} and 中{ちゅう}国{ごく} have the same on-reading for both kanji, however only the latter one gets voiced.

Comment: Are words like 手書き also considered Rendaku?  My instinct says yes, but I wanted to confirm.  I ask because がき is technically a reading of 書き。

Comment: @ajsmart Yes. It also shows up in people's names and compound verbs like 裏{うら}返{がえ}す. Also if you use jisho.org as your source you'll see it only lists it with a hyphen in front indicating it only gets that reading as a prefix.

Answer (score 3):

> Are they the same kanji?

Yes

> Is "gen" an unofficial reading or something?

I'm not sure if it's unofficial, but you can and sometimes do read it as ゲン。

---

You occasionally voice some kanji readings, but I can't exactly explain why.  It has to do with the sound before the character, but I haven't studied enough kanji to make sense of it.

Another great example of this is: [手紙{てがみ}](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%89%8B%E7%B4%99) 。  Looking at jisho.org, you will find that [がみ is not listed as a reading](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%B4%99%20%23kanji), but it is still read てがみ。

I'm not privy on the rules if there are any, but this sort of thing happens a lot.