# Why is it that when words get combined, the sound often gets softened?

Tags: rendaku

I can't come up with an example right now.  But hypothetically let's say there was a word that was ka. And they combined it with ku to make a new word. then it'd  become kagu instead of kaku. It usually gets softened like that. Why is that?

Comment: A good example for this would be a word like 口｛くち｝becoming softened when joined with 入｛い｝り to form 入｛い｝り口｛ぐち｝

Comment: You'll like this answer: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/48895/22352